# making algorithm for cut String android

Tags: android, string, algorithm

I have received a trame (String  contents some information (Product and Price) Like "/tomatos*500/botot*1200/tor*1200") and I need to cut that string to make it items into ArrayList
and Product contents ( String product, String Price).

Here is a data sample

> "/**banana*200**/**tomatos*7850**/**falfoul*10**/**Egg*1200**/**kiwi*100**"

I have tried this algorithm:

```
 String[] decouped_product = post.toString().split("/");
                for(int i = 0 ; i <decouped_product.length;i++){
                    Log.d("decoupage1",decouped_product[i]);
                    if(decouped_product[i].equals("")){

                    }else {
                        String[] decouped_prix = post.toString().split("\\*");
                        String Product_nom = decouped_prix[0];
                        String Prix = decouped_prix[1];
                        Log.d("nom: ",Product_nom);
                        Log.d("prix: ",Prix);
                    }

                }
                Log.d("changed file",post.toString());
```

but it doesn't work it give me

nom: tomatos

prix: *500/botot

something like that.
but I want it like:

nom: tomatos

prix: 500

nom: botot

prix: 1200

nom: tor

prix: 1200

Comment: post the full example of the received text. isn't it json?

Comment: no just string and It come from a C# application, I want to make algorithm that can split characters into / / and make the right of * character into product field and the left into the price like: /banana*4000 want to be nom: banana ana Prix: 4000

Comment: ok then paste a sample.

Comment: Ok there are two possibilities it can come with one product like : "/banana*200"
or with multiple like: "/banana*200/tomatos*7850/falfoul*10/Egg*1200/kiwi*100" 
isn't it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
 String[] decouped_product = post.toString().split("/");
                for(int i = 0 ; i <decouped_product.length;i++){
                    Log.d("decoupage1",decouped_product[i]);
                    if(decouped_product[i].equals("")){

                    }else {
                        String[] decouped_prix = decouped_product[i].toString().split("\\*");
                        String Product_nom = decouped_prix[0];
                        String Prix = decouped_prix[1];
                        Log.d("nom: ",Product_nom);
                        Log.d("prix: ",Prix);
                    }

                }
                Log.d("changed file",post.toString());
```